# Geodesic identity map: why do these conditions ensure the geodesic map becomes identity?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

> Let $S$ be a closed, connected regular surface, so that any two points of $S$ can be connected by a geodesic. Suppose that $\phi: S \to S$ is a smooth map with the property that it sends geodesics to geodesics, i.e., for every geodesic $\gamma(t)$, the curve $(\phi\circ\gamma)(t)$ is again a geodesic.
>
> Prove that if there exists $p \in S$ such that $\phi(p) = p$ and $d\phi(p) = \operatorname{Id}$, then $\phi$ is the identity map.

I understand how knowing $\phi(p) = p$ is helpful but do not see how $d\phi(p) = \operatorname{Id}$ helps. Further, I am confused on how to put these conditions together to prove the statement. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer but a comment to help visualize. On the 2d sphere $S$, take a rotation $\phi$ with axis the two poles. Then if $p$ is the north pole, $\phi(p)=p$. Can you see why in that particular case, the condition $d\phi(p) = id_{T_pS}$ assures that $\phi = id$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That visualization does help a bit. So does ()= just guarentree that the geodesic will be going in the same direction?

Comment: Not "just" that, because "uniqueness of geodesics". :)